# call procedure which is inside a package in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g, procedure, overloading

how to call procedure which is inside a package in oracle 10g.
           i have a two procedure called "area" which is of one parameter and other is also "area" but with 3 parameters. in short procedures are overloaded inside a package "shapearea".

```
create or replace package shapearea is
procedure area(l in number);
procedure area(l in number,b in number,h in number);
end;


create or replace package body shapearea is

 procedure area (l in number) is
 begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Area of '||'l'||' lengh circle is'||l*l);
 end;

procedure area (l in number,b in number,h in number) is
 begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Area of '||'l'||' lengh ractangle is'||l*b*h);
 end;

end;
```

i tried

```
execute shapearea.area(5);
exec shapearea.area(5);
call shapearea.area(5);
shapearea.area(5);
```

but it did not work in oracle 10g.

Comment: "it did not work" is not a valid error message.

Comment: it gives "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement" error message.

Comment: You have listed four lines of code, none of which are valid SQL statements - so what did you expect? :)

Comment: I just need to call procedure within package,but i don't know how to call it in oracle 10g,so i tried above 4 alternatives,but it didn't work. but now i know, using PL/SQL block i can call procedures or functions within the package.

Comment: In oracle 8i all above first 3 statements are valid.

Comment: There is a difference between a **SQL** statement and a **PL/SQL** expression. Your statements are *not* SQL statements. Thus the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL*Plus then try:

```
set serveroutput on
Begin
  shapearea.area(5);
end;
/
```

If you are using SQL Developer you need to show the DBMS_Output window and enable it for the connection you are using.

[`DBMS_OUTPUT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#BABJCAJA) does not actually write to your display on its own.  In reality it just buffers the output to some internal data structures, and then in the case of SQL*Plus, the `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` enables client side routines to retrieve the output.  In the case of SQL Developer showing the DBMS Output window and enabling it for the connection you are using enables it's client side display routines.

For other environments you may need to programatically read out the buffered results with the `GET_LINE` and/or `GET_LINES` [`DBMS_OUTPUT` functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#BABJCAJA).

Comment: You don't need set serveroutput on in oracle 10g, otherwise your solution is  completely true.

Comment: how can i directly call procedure in package in oracle 10g without using pl/sql block.

Comment: The `set serveroutput on` statement is so the user's `dbms_output.put_line` statements will be shown.  The last time I checked  (just now `;^)`) serveroutput in SQL*Plus didn't default to on.

Comment: @TanvirPatel you can use `exec shapearea.area(5);` instead but that's just shorthand for an anonymous pl/sql block.

Comment: i m running it on oracle 10g database express edition.not on sqlplus.

Comment: SQL*Plus is just a tool you might use to connect to the database.  If you aren't using SQL*Plus, then the `set` statement doesn't apply, and will instead need to be something more appropriate for which ever client you are using such as the instructions I provided for SQL Developer.  Those are the only development clients of note that I use.